# Assigning buttons to specific keys

Tags: c#, winforms

Good day! I want a button behave like the enter key and another to behave like the backspace key. Has anyone got any ideas how this can be done please?

Comment: Which API are you using? Windows Forms? WPF?

Comment: I'm using Windows forms

Answer (score 0):

Set the `KeyPreview` property on your form to true. And set AcceptButton to the button.

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     // When this property is set to true, the form will receive all 
     // KeyPress, KeyDown, and KeyUp events. 
     this.KeyPreview = true;

     //This property enables you to designate a default action to occur when the 
     //user presses the ENTER key in your application. 
     this.AcceptButton = button1;

     this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
}
```

Just hande Form `KeyDown` event and check pressed keys for other keys than ENTER.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
     {
         BackSpaceButton_Click(null, null);  // Or do whatever you want
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have, maybe it might be the conditional formatiing i have on my text boxes. I have multiple text boxes and once any of them have focus, I want to press the button (which acts as the enter key) and focus on the next one..Do i need to implement a focus function in the code somewhere?

Comment: @user3422075 If you handled KeyDown event of the form, it must execute event handler even the focus on the one of the textboxes.

Comment: @user3422075 Check this. I have updated answer. ` this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;`

Answer (score 0):

For Enter Button : If you set your Form's AcceptButton property to one of the Buttons on the form, you'll get that behaviour by default.

Otherwise

Set the KeyPreview property to True on the form and handle its KeyDown event. You can do like this

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    this.KeyDown += Form1_KeyDown;
}
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
            ProcessTabKey(true);//this will move textbox focus on Enter Key pressed.
    } 
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
    {
        BackSpaceButton_Click(null,null);//this is a button event,it fire when you press Back key
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't worked for me, I have tried both methods

Comment: What is happening with the above code.?is your requirement is like on Enter key pressed,the focus has to move to next TextBox...? What functionality you want to do when Enter Key and Back Key pressed..?

Comment: I pressed the button and doesn't do anything. I have multiple text boxes and once any of them have focus, I want to press the button (which acts as the enter key) and focus on the next one..Do i need to implement a focus function in the code somewhere?

Comment: Please post your code what you tried now.I have multiple text boxes and once any of them have focus, I want to press the button (which acts as the enter key) and focus on the next one.?This means you want to move TextBox focus to Another TextBox on Enter key pressed..?

Comment: there are multiple conditions so its too long to post and yes i want TextBox focus to Another TextBox on Enter key pressed but i dont want to use the enter key on the keyboard, I want to use a button instead to trigger the enterkey to focus on the next textbox

Comment: private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
      ProcessTabKey(true);
} This code Will move focus from one text box to another on Enter key Pressed..Go to Form properties and Set KeyPreview to True.

Comment: still no luck I'm afraid

Comment: Thank You for your efforts though :)

Comment: Have you created Form1_KeyDown Event..?See my Edited answer.If you post your code,we can try to solve your problem

Comment: private void bEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((textBox1.focus() == true) || (textBox2.focus() == true) || (textBox2.focus() == true)) //and so on
            {
                //bEnter = Enter button
                //Focus on the next textbox
            }

        }

Comment: thats essentially what i want to achieve

Comment: private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
            bEnter_Click(null,null);
    }} Try this

Comment: Post you full Form1.cs code then only we can solve your problem.

Comment: its far too long to post but i posted the main bit earlier. Thanks for your efforts again, my requests were just extra features i thought i could implement into the program but it's not too important if i don't include it.

Comment: Place a break point in the code and check where it is hitting when you press Enter key in your Keyboard.